# I have to add Weather extension in my gnome3 toolbar

Tags: gnome

I want to add a weather extension to my gnome3 toolbar but I cant get anything working.

I am using ubuntu 12.10 with gnome3.

I tried to add this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-weather
```

but the last command doest work it says that it cant locate such file.

I installed this https://launchpad.net/weather-indicator.

But I cant seem to get it to show on the gnome toolbar.
It only shows here [image: http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/4108/weatherhl.png].

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't like that very much check [neroth fork](http://www.my-guides.net/en/guides/linux/353-alternative-gnome-shell-weather-extension-by-neroth)